# Matrix should be outside the page margins

Tags: margins, matrices

I have a problem with the following matrix, because of its complexity it is hardly readable when written inside the margins (which is the case below). How can I expand the matrix outside of the page margins?

```
\begin{equation}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\resizebox{1 \textwidth}{!} 
{$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{A} \\
U_{B} \\
U_{C} \\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
R_A+R_{G}+j(X_{AA}+X_{G}) & R_{G}+j(X_{AB}+X_{G})& R_{G}+j(X_{AC}+X_{G}) & R_{G}+j(X_{AN}+X_{G}) \\
R_{G}+j(X_{BA}+X_{G}) & R_B+R_{G}+j(X_{BB}+X_{G})  & R_{G}+j(X_{BC}+X_{G}) & R_{G}+j(X_{BN}+X_{G}) \\
R_{G}+j(X_{CA}+X_{G}) & R_{G}+j(X_{CB}+X_{G})  & R_C+R_{G}+j(X_{CC}+X_{G}) & R_{G}+j(X_{CN}+X_{G})\\
R_{G}+j(X_{NA}+X_{G}) & R_{G}+j(X_{NB}+X_{G})  & R_{G}+j(X_{NC}+X_{G}) & R_N+R_{G}+j(X_{NN}+X_{G})\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{A} \\
I_{B} \\
I_{C} \\
I_{N} \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
Z_{AA} & Z_{AB}& Z_{AC}& Z_{AN}  \\
Z_{BA} & Z_{BB}& Z_{BC}& Z_{BN}  \\
Z_{CA} & Z_{CB}& Z_{CC} & Z_{CN} \\
Z_{NA} & Z_{NB}& Z_{NC} & Z_{NN} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{A} \\
I_{B} \\
I_{C} \\
I_{N} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= Z_{ABC} \begin{bmatrix}
I_{A} \\
I_{B} \\
I_{C} \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{aligned}
$}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `\resizebox` should be the very last resort. I believe you get a much better presentation if you use a shorthand for the common terms in the big matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{A} \\
U_{B} \\
U_{C} \\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
R_A+T_{AA} & T_{AB} & T_{AC} & T_{AN} \\
T_{BA} & R_B+T_{BB} & T_{BC} & T_{BN} \\
T_{CA} & T_{CB} & R_C+T_{CC} & T_{CN} \\
T_{NA} & T_{NB} & T_{NC} & R_N+T_{NN}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{A} \\
I_{B} \\
I_{C} \\
I_{N} \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
Z_{AA} & Z_{AB}& Z_{AC}& Z_{AN}  \\
Z_{BA} & Z_{BB}& Z_{BC}& Z_{BN}  \\
Z_{CA} & Z_{CB}& Z_{CC} & Z_{CN} \\
Z_{NA} & Z_{NB}& Z_{NC} & Z_{NN} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{A} \\
I_{B} \\
I_{C} \\
I_{N} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= Z_{ABC} \begin{bmatrix}
I_{A} \\
I_{B} \\
I_{C} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where
\[
T_{hk}=R_G+j(X_{hk}+X_G)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. +1. But I am wondering why the mathematician in you did not revolt. (I'm wondering about the last equality.)

Comment: @marmot I don't know what those terms represent, but indeed the last object seems misplaced.